# Passing JWT Token as QueryString to SignalR Hub

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Trying to follow the suggestions in the link below to pass a `JWT` token to my SignalR hub but so far it's not working. In particular, see David Fowler's suggestion on July 22, 2017. https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/130

My frontend is `React` so I'm simply adding the token to the querystring as follows where `_token` has my `JWT` token value:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/myhub?AUTHORIZATION=" + _token)
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
```

In the `ConfigureServices()` method of my `Startup.cs`, I have the following configuration for `Jwt` tokens:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
              .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
                  jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
                  jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
                  jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                  {
                      OnMessageReceived = context =>
                      {
                          if(context.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                              context.Token = context.Request.Query["AUTHORIZATION"];

                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                      }
                  };
              });
```

And this is what my `Hub` looks like:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
   private IBackendService _backendService;
   public MyHub(IBackendService backendService)
   {
       _backendService = backendService;
   }

   public async Task SendMessage(string message)
   {
       // Regular SignalR stuff
       // SignalR will now send the message to all connected users...
   }
}
```

Basically, I'm getting the `401 Unauthorized` error.

I put a break point where I check to see if the request is a web sockets request but I'm not hitting it. Looks like something in the pipeline is determining that the user is not authenticated.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: it seems like we're working on a few things similar.  If you have any additional question, just ping me on here. I'd be glad to help

Comment: @johnny5 Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. I haven't gone over the whole code yet but accepted your solution as the answer so please don't get mad at me if I bug you with some questions.

Comment: no worries, you can bug me anytime, I'll always be available to help, I just recently went though these struggles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by using custom middleware to handle grabbing the authentication token from the query string.

```
public class SignalRQueryStringAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SignalRQueryStringAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // Convert incomming qs auth token to a Authorization header so the rest of the chain
    // can authorize the request correctly
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers["Connection"] == "Upgrade" &&
            context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("authToken", out var token))
        {
            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.First());
        }
         await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public static class SignalRQueryStringAuthExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSignalRQueryStringAuth(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<SignalRQueryStringAuthMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

This will try to get the query string value "authToken" and it will set the heads so you can leverage your authentication middleware.  You need to call this before the authentication middleware in the pipeline like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...

    app.UseSignalRQueryStringAuth();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    //...
}
```

**EDIT**

on a side note you should only append the token if the user is logged in:

```
if (accessToken) {
    hubUrl += '?authToken' +'=' + accessToken;
}

this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                                .withUrl(hubUrl)
                                .build();
```

Comment: hold on I need to post a snippet from the client as well

Comment: It's all pretty clear except one area: looks like in the middleware, you're looking for `Headers["Connection"] == "Upgrade"`. Does this mean you're setting a custom header named `Connection` with a value of `Upgrade` in SignalR connection? If so, where are you adding it? Clearly, we're trying to limit the work we do in the middleware to SignalR connections only. Do you find that adding this header is the best way to do this? I've seen people either check the path in `context.Request` or in David Fowler's example, he's doing `context.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest`.

Comment: I think that is a check limits it to signalr but lemme check if I can find the documentation on that

Comment: Thanks! I just tried Fowler's approach but I keep getting `false` on `context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest`. In browser console, I do see that a connection is established but I never hit my break point because `IsWebSocketRequest` is always false. Ultimately, my call to SignalR hub is failing with unauthorized request which makes sense because the middleware is never grabbing the token to put it in the header. So that one `if` statement is where I'm having trouble right now.

Comment: @Sam, I found where I originally got the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1130)

Comment: Yes, interestingly it seems to work fine with that header. Let me look into this a bit more to see if it's working all the time. Earlier, it was a bit hit and miss. Thanks again. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Sam Connection Header is used to tell the server to keep the connection alive etc. the upgrade value is to upgrade connection to websocket,

Comment: If you add `app.UseWebSockets();` in the `Configure()` method of `Startup.cs`, we can use `context.Websockets.IsWebSocketRequest` to check if the request is an incoming request for `SignalR` -- assuming you don't use `WebSockets` any other way. The trick is to use it before `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseSignalR()`.

Comment: @Sam thanks I’ll modify my code, that will be a whole lot clearing then using that header

Comment: I think so too. Here's the link to the GitHub questions I posted. I always feel better when I get an answer from the team who created the technology: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/130#issuecomment-404721480

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented this in my project. The shortest way of doing this is to add a middleware to your Configure method.

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                context.Request.Headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
            }

            await next.Invoke().ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
```

It does the same thing as mentioned in the other answer. It adds the token to the header by reading it from the query string. Of course, you can separate out the implementation of custom middleware in a separate file.