# StringValues Count shows 1 even when value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm reading a token from `QueryString` in my ASP.NET Core app and I'm confused about something.

Even when the `StringValues` has `null` value, its `Count` is showing 1 -- see below.

[image]

I also tried `StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(token)` and that's failing too. How do I reliably check to see if `StringValues` truly has useful data in it?

UPDATE:
The code that reads the value is as follows:

```
if(path.StartsWith("/im") && context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("access_token", out var token))
{
   context.Token = token;
}
```

I'm sending an access_token from my client like so:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/myhub?AUTHORIZATION=" + _token)
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] and the **exact** complete url. _Note the value is **not** `null` it is `"null"`._

Comment: String has a literal value "null".

Comment: Just so the picture is clearer. I'm doing this in my ASP.NET Core app with SignalR. Web sockets don't send the `JWT` token in headers so the SignalR team recommends sending the token in a `QueryString`. This is where I'm having this behavior.

Comment: If that is the case then (by definition) the complete URL can't be `http://localhost:45978/im`. Can you please check your browser (Chrome Developer Tools) and confirm the **exact** complete url?

Comment: We are not asking you to guess or hypothesise. Please provide the **exact** complete url. _I know this is frustrating for you - but it is likely the issue is the way you are generating the url. We really need to know what it is to know where you made the mistake and work backwards to the cause._ Please share the value of `context.Request.QueryString`.

Comment: @Sam is there a chance that your token is still appended to the query string even if the value is null? btw. there is a few custom middlewares to handle signalr tokens in the query string,

Comment: Just one second... The one kind of unusual message I'm seeing is that Chrome is "normalizing" my URL. As I create the connection for SignalR, I define the URL as "/im" in my code but looks like Chrome is "normalizing" it. Never seen that before.

Comment: @johnny5 Can you point me in the right direction for those middleware? This has been rather frustrating as it is. The idea simply is to pass my `JWT` token so that I can ask my hub to only accept requests from authenticated users.

Comment: @Sam I lost the link to the original github gyst, but if you modify the question to be about Signalr tokens I'll post the code as an answer I have it right here

Comment: @johnny5 I have another open question where you can post the answer. Here's the link to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313837/passing-jwt-token-as-querystring-to-signalr-hub

Comment: @Sam Thanks I'll post the full sample there

Comment: Any luck getting the actual complete URL @Sam?

Comment: As @johnny5 pointed out, the issue here is that I was appending the token even if the user was not authenticated and as a result, the front end was setting thevalue to "null". Thank you for engaging with this issue. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in this case is you're appending the access_token even if the user is logged in. So when you go to access it it has the value of "null" which is sent from the client.

You just need to conditionally append the value

```
if (accessToken) {
    hubUrl += '?authToken' +'=' + accessToken;
}

this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl(hubUrl)
                            .build();
```